# unable to update HTTPD, mod_jk dependency error

Tags: rhel, software-installation, rpm

While trying to update httpd in RHEL6, getting some dependency error as below:

```
Unsatisfied dependencies for mod_jk-ap20-1.2.31-1.x86_64:
httpd = 2.2.3 is needed by mod_jk-ap20-1.2.31-1.x86_64
```

I am using `httpd-2.2.15-26.el6.x86_64`

Can any one explain please why `mod_jk` displays dependency as `httpd 2.2.3`?

Comment: Are you using `yum` ? Have to tried downloading updated RPMs of both httpd and mod_jk and updating them together?

Comment: i am using both Yum update httpd or rpm -Va to verify the dependencies. As i mentioned httpd (2.2.15) is already installed. i am not trying to update mod_jk and that too as per the error message it is asking for httpd (2.2.3) only but i have already httpd (2.2.15)